# Tableau report that aggregates the same row into multiple groups

Tags: tableau-api, aggregation

A vendor has many products in various product categories.  A new customer might buy items from one or multiple categories.  The data rows represent one order/item combination, such that if three items are bought in an order, there will be three rows in the data set.  When trying to answer the question of the average sales total by order category, I want to include each **order total** in every applicable category.  For example, if this is what happened:

```
 Customer #1:  Bought $20 in category A and $40 in category B.
 Customer #2:  Bought $40 in category B.
 Customer #3:  Bought $40 in category A and $30 in category C.
```

The data will show:

```
 Row 1:  Customer #1 bought $20 in category A.
 Row 2:  Customer #1 bought $40 in category B.
 Row 3:  Customer #2 bought $40 in category B.
 Row 4:  Customer #3 bought $40 in category A.
 Row 5:  Customer #3 bought $30 in category C.
```

My report should show:

```
 Category A:  Two customers, $130 total (**Not $60**).  Average sale per order = $65.  
 Category B:  Two customers, $100 total.  Average sale per order = $50.
 Category C:  One customer,  $70 total.  Average sale per order = $70.
```

Each order should get counted in its entirety in every applicable category. **This means that a given row of data will get aggregated into multiple category groups.**  How can I do this in Tableau?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for a [Level of Detail](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm) calc!  Fix to the Category...

```
{FIXED [Category] : SUM([Sales])/COUNT([Orders]) }
```

Be sure to check for division by zero.

**UPDATE**

In light of the new detail specifying that the data set is item level, not order level, you can count the distinct order numbers instead of counting the number of records.

```
{FIXED [Category] : SUM([Sales])/COUNTD([Order Number]) }
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an idea!  I've used LODs before.  I should have specified that the data set is one row per item per order, so for the example shown there are five records.  (I just edited the OP to show this.) Given this, wouldn't the LOD just aggregate only a given category's records into the calculation?  So I'd end up with Cat A average sale per order = 60/2 = 30  instead of 130/2 = 65?

Comment: @LarrySeligman - ok, then do a distinct count of the order number instead of counting the number of records...